# I have to add loader inside return pickupLocationsService (till get result from server side)

Tags: magento2, ajax, loader

/**

- Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
- See COPYING.txt for license details.
  */

define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'uiComponent',
'uiRegistry',
'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter',
'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information',
'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend/js/model/pickup-locations-service',
'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data'
], function (
$,
_,
Component,
registry,
modal,
quote,
customer,
stepNavigator,
addressConverter,
setShippingInformationAction,
pickupLocationsService,
checkoutData
) {
'use strict';

```
return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend/store-selector',
        selectedLocationTemplate:
            'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend/store-selector/selected-location',
        storeSelectorPopupTemplate:
            'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend/store-selector/popup',
        storeSelectorPopupItemTemplate:
            'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend/store-selector/popup-item',
        loginFormSelector:
            '#store-selector form[data-role=email-with-possible-login]',
        defaultCountryId: window.checkoutConfig.defaultCountryId,
        delimiter: window.checkoutConfig.storePickupApiSearchTermDelimiter,
        selectedLocation: pickupLocationsService.selectedLocation,
        quoteIsVirtual: quote.isVirtual,
        searchQuery: '',
        nearbyLocations: null,
        isLoading: pickupLocationsService.isLoading,
        popup: null,
        searchDebounceTimeout: 300,
        imports: {
            nearbySearchRadius: '${ $.parentName }:nearbySearchRadius',
            nearbySearchLimit: '${ $.parentName }:nearbySearchLimit'
        }
    },

    /**
     * Init component
     *
     * @return {exports}
     */
    initialize: function () {

        var updateNearbyLocations, country;

        this._super();

        updateNearbyLocations = _.debounce(function (searchQuery) {
            country = quote.shippingAddress() && quote.shippingAddress().countryId ?
                quote.shippingAddress().countryId : this.defaultCountryId;
            searchQuery = this.getSearchTerm(searchQuery, country);
            this.updateNearbyLocations(searchQuery);
        }, this.searchDebounceTimeout).bind(this);
        this.searchQuery.subscribe(updateNearbyLocations);

        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Init component observable variables
     *
     * @return {exports}
     */
    initObservable: function () {

        return this._super().observe(['nearbyLocations', 'searchQuery']);
    },

    /**
     * Set shipping information handler
     */
    setPickupInformation: function () {
        var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();

        if (this.validatePickupInformation()) {
            shippingAddress = addressConverter.quoteAddressToFormAddressData(shippingAddress);
            checkoutData.setShippingAddressFromData(shippingAddress);
            setShippingInformationAction().done(function () {
                stepNavigator.next();
            });
        }
    },

    /**
     * @return {*}
     */
    getPopup: function () {

        if (!this.popup) {
            this.popup = modal(
                this.popUpList.options,
                $(this.popUpList.element)
            );
        }

        return this.popup;
    },

    /**
     * Get Search Term from search query and country.
     *
     * @param {String} searchQuery
     * @param {String} country
     * @returns {String}
     */
    getSearchTerm: function (searchQuery, country) {

        return searchQuery ? searchQuery + this.delimiter + country : searchQuery;
    },

    /**
     * @returns void
     */
    openPopup: function () {
        var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress(),
            country = shippingAddress.countryId ? shippingAddress.countryId :
            this.defaultCountryId,
            searchTerm = '';

        this.getPopup().openModal();

        if (shippingAddress.city && shippingAddress.postcode) {
            searchTerm = this.getSearchTerm(shippingAddress.postcode, country);
        }

        this.updateNearbyLocations(searchTerm);
    },

    /**
     * @param {Object} location
     * @returns void
     */
    selectPickupLocation: function (location) {

        pickupLocationsService.selectForShipping(location);
        this.getPopup().closeModal();
    },

    /**
     * @param {Object} location
     * @returns {*|Boolean}
     */
    isPickupLocationSelected: function (location) {
        return _.isEqual(this.selectedLocation(), location);
    },

    /**
     * @param {String} searchQuery
     * @returns {*}
     */
    updateNearbyLocations: function (searchQuery) {
        var self = this,
            productsInfo = [],
            items = quote.getItems(),
            searchCriteria;

        _.each(items, function (item) {
            if (item['qty_options'] === undefined || item['qty_options'].length === 0) {
                productsInfo.push(
                    {
                        sku: item.sku
                    }
                );
            }
        });

        searchCriteria = {
            extensionAttributes: {
                productsInfo: productsInfo
            },
            pageSize: this.nearbySearchLimit
        };

        if (searchQuery) {
            searchCriteria.area = {
                radius: this.nearbySearchRadius,
                searchTerm: searchQuery
            };
        }

        return pickupLocationsService
            .getNearbyLocations(searchCriteria)
            .then(function (locations) {
                self.nearbyLocations(locations);
            })
            .fail(function () {
                self.nearbyLocations([]);
            });
    },

    /**
     * @returns {Boolean}
     */
    validatePickupInformation: function () {
        var emailValidationResult,
            loginFormSelector = this.loginFormSelector;

        if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
            $(loginFormSelector).validation();
            emailValidationResult = $(loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').valid() ? true : false;

            if (!emailValidationResult) {
                $(this.loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').focus();

                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

});